# How to make swipe between Controllers with animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiviewcontroller, swipe

I have my structure like

Controller 1 <-> Controller 2 <-> Controller 3 <-> ...<->Controller N

I need to be able to access to controller 1 or 3 directly from another controllers. I need swipe animation between controllers 1-n , and navigation bar with < and > buttons.

What is the best solution for this swiping controllers? I need be able to do some animation there. Do i need use paged `UIScrollView`? or `UIPageViewController`? With animation - `CALayer` transition? 
Please, help me to choose.

Comment: Try to use ready 3rd party libraries like e.g. https://github.com/mglagola/MGSwipeTabBarController. I think it will fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Alexander and anyone else who needs a solution to this problem,
I think the easiest way to deal with this situation would be to use the UIGestures which will give great animations and will simply be justified using the storyboard. To use it from one view controller to the other, just do the following:

If your side view is open, this will show up on the bottom right side of the storyboard:
[image]

Then, you will have to drag the swipe gesture recognizer to the initial view controller and then let go when the whole view is highlighted in blue:

[image]

After that, you will have to control-drag the gesture icon on the top of the initial view controller to the controller you want to connect to. Then it will show a drop down list after you let go of the highlighted controller. Pick any segue:

[image]

You can do this with all the view controllers by creating more gestures and segues. You can also do it from the same view controller back or even skip controllers with different types of gesture recognizers.

I hoped it helped :)